# jquery validation by pushing key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some validation in jquery, I need to prevent user right when try to enter number or other invalid characters in the LastName textbox. I put the validation code inside the  keypress function as follows, but it does not let user enter anything, it lock all the keys.

```
   $('#LastName').keypress(function () {
    var lastName = $.trim($('#LastName').val() || '');
    if (lastName.length == 0 || !lastNameregx.test(lastName)) {
        $(this).addClass('ChangetoYellow');
        if ($(this).next().hasClass('Required'))
            $(this).next().remove();
        $(this).after('<div class="Required">Enter valid LastName.</div>');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $(this).next(".Required").remove();
        $(this).removeClass('ChangetoYellow');
        return true;
    }
});
```

and this is the regx

```
 var lastNameregx = /^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Comment: What is in your `lastNameregx`?

Comment: @Uzbekjon var lastNameregx = /^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/;